# How to shut down macOS from a launch daemon? And different ways to reboot

Tags: c++, macos, shutdown

I'm looking for a low-level shut-down from my macOS launch daemon written in C++.

I found out that doing the following reboots it:

```
#include <sys/reboot.h>

if(reboot(RB_AUTOBOOT) != 0)
{
    log("Reboot failed, err=%d", errno);
}
```

Two part question:

1. I can't seem to find how to shut it down?
2. The reboot I showed above seems like a fast power action that gives applications no chance to save data. Am I correct? If so, what is a way to do it by letting other apps to respond to a reboot/shutdown?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/238807/how-can-i-invoke-mac-os-x-shutdown-programmatically, https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1134/_index.html

Comment: That seems like a high-level action, and on macOS that means AppleScript as in the link above.

Comment: You have this tagged FreeBSD but macOS is not FreeBSD.

Comment: @jtbandes: thanks. It works as a "soft" shutdown or reboot with the `kAEShutDown` and `kAERestart` flags respectively - or it shows a UI and blocks the shutdown for apps that want to warn a user. But what about a forced shutdown, kinda like what `reboot(RB_AUTOBOOT)` does for a restart? I can't seem to find which flags do I need to specify to make it shut-down instead.

Comment: I don't understand your question, are you asking for a forced shutdown or a shutdown that allows other apps to respond? If the latter, why isn't `kAEShutDown` a good solution for you?

Comment: @jtbandes: kAEShutDown doesn't perform a forced shutdown.